# SonarCloud shows coverage for test class although test classes are excluded

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarcloud

I have set up SonarCloud analysis for a Java project which triggers analysis when a PR is created on the git repository.

The command for triggering the check in my `.travis.yml` file is:

```
mvn clean compile test dependency:copy-dependencies
sonar-scanner 
-Dsonar.projectKey=project-key 
-Dsonar.java.binaries=project/target/classes 
-Dsonar.java.test.binaries=project/target/test-classes 
-Dsonar.java.libraries=project/target/dependency 
-Dsonar.java.test.libraries=project/target/dependency 
-Dsonar.test.exclusions=project/src/test/**/*Test.java
```

**What is expected**
If someone checks-in code in a Pull Request that has a test class then it should not be considered for coverage. Only the target class should be.

**What is happening**
If I check-in 2 classes `SonarSample.java` and `SonarSampleTest.java` then SonarCloud shows coverage for both the classes.

[image]
How can I exclude the test class from being considered for coverage data?

Comment: What does the configuration of the `jacoco-maven-plugin` in your `pom.xml` look like?

Comment: You can use the property `sonar.coverage.exclusions` like you've used `sonar.test.exclusions`

Answer (score 0):

Note that coverage is displayed for files classified as *sources*, and not displayed for files classified as *tests*.

This looks like a mistake:

> ```
> -Dsonar.test.exclusions=project/src/test/**/*Test.java
> ```

If you want `*Test.java` files to be treated as tests, and thereby exclude them from sources and therefore coverage computations, then change that line to be an *inclusion* instead of an *exclusion*:

```
-Dsonar.test.inclusions=project/src/test/**/*Test.java
```

---

As an aside: why are you using `sonar-scanner` instead of `mvn sonar:sonar`?

Comment: Does `mvn sonar:sonar` support analysing pull requests?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `test.inclusions`. Let me try that out :)

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar `mvn sonar:sonar` supports analyzing pull requests the same way as `sonar-scanner`. You have to pass the required parameters with `-D...`, in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

In my root pom.xml, adding following two lines resolved the issue,

```
        <sonar.sources>**/main/java/**/*</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.inclusions>**/main/java/**/*</sonar.inclusions>
```

This doesn't count *Test.java files from src/test folder in coverage report.